# What does "blank" in Default Gateway mean?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, cable-modem

I have reinstalled Windows XP and posted about not being able to connect to the internet. I did go and ensure all drivers are there.

Now, when I type `ipconfig /all`, I get

- a physical address
- DHCP enabled
- autoconfiguration enabled
- autoconfiguration IP address
- subnet mask
- a line that says *default gateway*
  where *default gateway* is the only line with no numbers or anything next to it.

My wireless connection works, but how can I get this ethernet connection to work? This was working prior to this fresh reinstall.

Comment: Is there a router providing the IP address.  Is there a separate cable modem connected to the router?

Comment: I have the ethernet cable connected to the motorola surboad modem. Sorry, I am not sure what it means by modem connected to router. what I have is a cable modem with ethernet cable running from it connected to my laptop.  For my other laptop the connection is fine and gets online no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your key here is that you're seeing an autoconfiguration IP address (which likely is in the 169.254.x.x range) instead of a regular IP address.  This means that your computer is either not receiving or not detecting a reply from a DHCP server and is assigning itself an APIPA address.  If you're plugging your laptop directly into the cable modem then you should either be getting a private-range IP address or a public-range IP address, depending on which your cable company assigns to the client machines.  If you have plugged a different laptop into this modem and it is able to properly connect to the internet then you may have a bad NIC on your current laptop or the NIC's drivers may not be loaded properly.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling your NIC's drivers and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thank you I am learning alot here about this dhcp and internet connections. I have it working now:)

Answer (score 1):

Your gateway is the address your computer expects to route your traffic through in order to get to any address that is not on your immediate subnet. If there is no address under default gateway, then your traffic isn't leaving your subnet.

The most likely problem is that either your router is incorrectly configured, or you're not using DHCP and forgot to put in the default gateway when you keyed in your ip information.

I could tell you more, with more information.